# Setting a Watchpoint to Output a Hex List in GDB

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I'm debugging a C program with GDB and I've setup a watchpoint on a variable `uint8_t msg_bin_tst[64];`. When the watchpoint is triggered GDB outputs something like:

```
Watchpoint 4: msg_bin_tst
Old value = "@\001\000\067\335\002\033a32c85ba9dda45823be416246cf8b433baa068d7\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\017\000\000\000(\000\000"
New value = "@\001\000\067\335\002\033a32c85ba9dda45823be416246cf6cf8b433baa068d7\000\000\000\000\000\000\017\000\000\000(\000\000"
```

This is somewhat hard to interpret, is there a way to set the output format to be like `print/x`, that is, something along the lines of:

```
msg_bin_tst = {0x40, 0x1, 0x0, 0x37, 0xdd, 0x2, 0x1b, 0x61, 0x33, 0x32, 0x63, 0x38, 0x35, 0x62, 0x61, 0x39, 0x64, 0x64, 0x61, 0x34, 0x35, 0x38, 0x32, 0x33, 0x62, 0x65, 0x34, 0x31, 0x36, 0x32, 0x34, 0x36, 0x63, 0x66, 0x38, 0x62, 0x34, 0x33, 0x33, 0x62, 0x61, 0x61, 0x30, 0x36, 0x38, 0x64, 0x37, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xf, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x28, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gdb` prints your value according to the default format for uint8_t[64]. However `gdb` also allows you to change the way it prints a particual type. This is called `Python Pretty-Printers`. You can read about them here:

- http://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Developer_Guide/debuggingprettyprinters.html
- http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html#Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter

I don't have c++11 and in order to demonstrate an example I use `unsigned char` as a type. The printer for your type might look like:

```
$ cat my_priner.py
class CustomPrinter(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string(self):
        res = "{"
        for m in xrange(64):
          res += hex(int(self.val[m]))
          if m != 63:
            res += ", "
        res += " }"
        return res

def lookup_type (val):
    if str(val.type) == 'unsigned char [64]':
        return CustomPrinter(val)
    return None

gdb.pretty_printers.append (lookup_type)
```

And this is this printer in action for my variable `unsigned char  m[64];`:

```
$ gdb  -q -x my_priner.py  -ex "set pagination off" -ex "start" -ex "watch m" -ex "c"  ./main
Reading symbols from /home/main...done.
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x400590: file main.cpp, line 7.
Starting program: /home/main

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:7
7         memcpy(m, "He",2);
Watchpoint 2: m
Continuing.
Watchpoint 2: m

Old value = {0x48, 0x65, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 }
New value = {0x48, 0x65, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0 }
0x0000003c41288ac4 in memcpy () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

Comment: For some reason, using that python script makes both the old value and the new value the same.

Comment: Seems like a error. Although it is not clear if it is `gdb` or in my script. I'm going to check this issue next week.

Comment: I have checked the script but it seems there is no error in it. So I decided to file a bug to get some response from gdb developers: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17152

Comment: I have only looked at it briefly, so I could be off on this, but as far as I can tell, the Value object passed to python pretty printers in gdb is created from the type and address of the object. So when the watchpoint handler calls into python to print the old and new values, the python pretty printers will access the same memory in the inferior both times, retrieving the same values both times.

Comment: @Mark, I am observing a difference when python pretty printer is not used and when it is used. Whatever explanation migth be it is not expected behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Use `commands` to set command when the watchpoint is hit, for example:

```
(gdb) commands 2
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 2, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>print /x msg_bin_tst
>end
```

`2` is the number of watchpoint.  Then when the watchpoint is hit, the array will be dumped automatically.

You can refer the gdb manual:https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html.

Comment: Note that this won't work once you enter another function as it won't be able to find `msg_bin_tst`, better to find the actual address and use that.